# Election (1999) vote count

Tags: plot-explanation, election

In the movie [Election](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0126886/), when McAllister secretly disposes two of Tracy's votes to reduce her vote count by 2, won't it also alter the vote counts for the Vice President? Since for both president and vice president, students voted in the same sheet.

His students could have stated this and proved their count is correct. So, is this a plot hole or they did not count votes for vice president?

Comment: Was the vice president race as close as the one for school president? If not, they might not be paying attention to the vice president votes at all. In a school election for student office, do they only count the votes for students attending school the day of the election? Would the people tallying the votes consider that?

Answer (score 2):

No, Mr. M instructs the student to perform the count for president first. That why there is two stacks, one for Tracy and one for Paul.